# Merchandising categories at store level

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1.14

We are about to begin working on an addition to Magento 1.14.2 EE that will allow us to merchandise and sort products within categories at a store level.  currently we do this by having 3 entirely separate root category trees, our editors are finding this cumbersome, and our indexing takes 3x the time it should take to reindex a single tree.

The plan is to add a `store_id` column to the catalog_category_product table which currently stores the `product_id`, `category_id` and products position within the category in question.

So my questions are fairly general at this point, has anyone attempted this previously and are there any obvious pitfalls that we are likely to encounter as a result of attempting this?  The solution to us seems fairly obvious yet it hasn't been implemented yet by Magento, surely this is a piece of functionality that would be useful for any company that has a presence in multiple countries.